# Laravel Eloquent Can't Get Attribute When I Use Find

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to return email of the user like in example:

```
public function getUserEmailAttribute()
{
    $user = User::find($this->used_by);
    return $user->email;
}
```

When I use $this->used_by it's throw me this error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/mertindervish/Documents/school/app/views/admin/invitation/list.blade.php)
```

But when I use a string like '2', '3' it's working. Is there any problem with my code? I tried to var_dump $this->used_by and it's return string(1).

Comment: Maybe try `$this->attributes['used_by']` instead of `$this->used_by`

Comment: it's still same error

Comment: Is it possible that one invitation doesn't have a valid user assigned in `used_by`. So the whole thing is crashing because of one?

Comment: where is this `function#getUserEmailAttribute` being defined, what file/class?

Comment: Yes, I saw it now that one invitation have not valid `used_by`. When I change it to valid id it's worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that one invitation didn't have a valid `used_by` value.

To prevent such an error in the future, add a null check:

```
public function getUserEmailAttribute()
{
    $user = User::find($this->used_by);
    if(is_null($user)) return null;
    return $user->email;
}
```